# Flutter VideoPlayerController network request from web api

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, .net, flutter

I am making a flutter app and using the VideoPlayerController library package and requesting video content via network:

```
VideoPlayerController newController = VideoPlayerController.network(
            "http://192.168.1.1:9999/S3/get-object/name-of-video.mp4");
```

My Web API Backend is .NET Core 3 and the controller endpoint is this:

```
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpGet("get-object/{url}")]
        public async Task<FileStreamResult> GetObject(string url)
        {
            // Seperate out only the filename
            string[] res = url.Split(new string[] { "%2F" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

            string fileName = res.LastOrDefault();

            Stream imageStream = await S3Helper.ReadObjectData(_appSettings, fileName);

            Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", new ContentDisposition
            {
                FileName = fileName,
                Inline = true // false = prompt the user for downloading; true = browser to try to show the file inline
            }.ToString());


            if (fileName.Contains(".jpg") || fileName.Contains(".jpeg"))
            {
                return File(imageStream, "image/jpeg");

            }
            else if (fileName.Contains(".png"))
            {
                return File(imageStream, "image/png");
            }
            else if (fileName.Contains(".mp4"))
            {
                return File(imageStream, new MediaTypeHeaderValue("video/mp4").MediaType, true);
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
                

        }
```

However, when I create a widget that uses a Network image, it actually works. I'm not sure what the difference is.

```
                                    CachedNetworkImage(
                                      imageUrl: "http://192.168.1.1:9999/S3/get-object/name-of-image.jpg",
                                      placeholder: (context, url) =>
                                          CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                      errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                                          Icon(Icons.error),
                                      fit: BoxFit.contain,
                                    ),
```

The .Net Core Backend has the video coming via an http get request as an inline video, similar to this one:

https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/butterfly.mp4

The error I get from my flutter app shows up like this:

Source error. E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(24687): com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$HttpDataSourceException: Unable to connect to http://192.168.1.1:9999/S3/get-object/name-of-video.mp4

Comment: Did you initialize the video controller after defining?

Comment: Yes, it was working when I had a direct link to my aws s3 object. Right now I have my Web API get the object, then serve it. When I changed it to use my Web API endpoint instead as a middle man, for security reasons, it no longer worked.

Comment: So i ran my app in --verbose mode and i saw a Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted for android so I fixed it by adding "android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" to the application in the android manifest.xml file!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about ios. But android doesn't allow http://. You need to provide a link starting https://.
To allow the http:// or others
add this line on androids AndroidManifest.xml.
Location android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

```
 android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

This should look like this:
[image]